# How to use datepicker in CodeIgniter?

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, twitter-bootstrap-3, datepicker

why is it when i tried clicking the calendar icon for the **datepicker**, it wont pop up the calendar. I'm using this one **[bootstrap-datepicker](http://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/)**. Here's the code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label for="dob">Date of Birth</label>
      <div class="input-group date">
         <input type="text" class="form-control">
             <div class="input-group-addon">
                 <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span>
              </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$('.input-group.date').datepicker({
});
```

jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/1Lsfjdjf/

Comment: it kinda worked out but the calendar already showed up even though I haven't clicked the button yet. And when I tried to clicked the year and month. The values inside the calendar are in one line sir

Comment: you need the css file that comes with the js file, same with bootstrap

Answer (score 1):

In HTML

```
<input type="text" class="form-control form_datetime">
```

In JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".form_datetime").datetimepicker({format: 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:ii'});
</script>
```

[demo](http://www.malot.fr/bootstrap-datetimepicker/demo.php)

Comment: it still doesn't work sir. It gives an error saying " $(...).datetimepicker is not a function"

Comment: @KaelJasper he is using a different datepiker from yours

Answer (score 0):

Here is the example of datepicker

```
  <?php echo form_input('date',$data['date'],array('class' => 'form- 
   control','id'=>'date')); ?>
```

try this

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did. I downloaded AdminLTE, copy the bower_components files where I found the datepicker css, js and bootstrap.

HTML file

```
<div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Preferred Date" id="birthpicker" required>
        </div>
```

I place this JS code below above of the body closing tag.

```
<script>
$(function () {
    $('#birthpicker').datepicker({
        autoclose: true
    })
})
</script>
```

That's it.